# Textbox text as Object's name

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TextBox named "tb1" (Not real name).

I want to, when I click a button; create an "Product" object with the value of the "tb1" text.

Something like...

```
Product tb1.text = new Product();
```

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the constructor on the Product object so that it can accept a string parameter.

**Product object**:

```
public Product(string productName)
{
    //set product name variable using productName parameter
    _productName = productName;   
}
```

And then you can do something like this:

```
//set product name using new constructor
Product product = new Product(tb1.Text);
```

Comment: So that method goes inside the Product class right ? I'm new to OOP :P

Comment: Yes, it's an override for the constructor that accepts a string argument so you can set the product name during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Pass "tb1.text" to Product's constructor while creating with new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is trying to create a Product where the variable name is the content of tb1.Text. Far as I know, thats impossible. It'd be really confusing for anybody reading the code later anyway, so even if it is possible please don't do it. :)

If you're just trying to create a Product where the Product name is set to the value of tb1.Text, you can do this:

```
Product someProduct = new Product();
someProduct.Name = tb1.Text;
```

Or pass into the constructor like Arun mentioned.